# CSS Modules not working after upgrading nodejs version

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I upgraded the version of Node JS on the project from v12 to v14 and with that some of the packages including laravel-mix v6.0.18.Through-out the project there are these css modules ":global(selector)" being used , that after updating are not working.

I tried adding css-loader as a module in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use : [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]} // there are some other babel rules as well.
```

After running `npm run watch` and it compiles it shows this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/fontello.css (./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-7[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-7[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-23[0].rules[0].use[0]!./resources/css/fontello.css)
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):  
  SyntaxError

  (1:1) C:\Users\osman\Desktop\Projects\mywebsite\resources\css\fontello.css Unknown word

  > 1 | // Imports
      | ^
    2 | import ___CSS_LOADER_API_NO_SOURCEMAP_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/noSourceMaps.js";
    3 | import ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js";
```

There are 14 errors exactly the same as this that appear, just the path `./resources/css/fontello.css` changes.

In the browser console the error appears like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) C:\Users\osman\Desktop\Projects\mywebsite\resources\css\theme\index.css Unknown word
[1m[31m>[39m[22m[90m 1 | [39m// Imports
 [90m   | [39m[1m[31m^[39m[22m
 [90m 2 | [39mimport ___CSS_LOADER_API_NO_SOURCEMAP_IMPORT___ from [32m"../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/noSourceMaps.js"[39m[33m;[39m
 [90m 3 | [39mimport ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from [32m"../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js"[39m[33m;[39m
```

Any help would be appreciated.